# 1 ServerName for 2 ServerPath (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, apache2, virtualhost, yii2

I've installed [Yii2 advanced application template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/apps-advanced.md). But have a problem with virtual hosts.

I want to run frontend part with url: `http://test_project/` and backend part with: `http://test_project/app/`.

But when I open `http://test_project/app/` (frontend part works fine) I get 404 error.
This is my `vhosts config`:

```
#test_project frontend
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername test_project
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test_project/frontend/web
    <Directory /var/www/test_project/frontend/web>
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#test_project backend
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test_project/backend/web
    Servername test_project
    ServerPath /app/
    RewriteEngine On
    <Directory /var/www/test_project/backend/web>
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

`Note`: due to some restrictions I can't to use subdomains (but it works fine).

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you check your Apache logs?

Comment: Hi @userid53, thanks for your response. Sure, I've checked logs. Nothing about vhosts problem, just message with 404 code in the apache access.log.